React Native iOS app crashes on launch with error: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
Suddenly after a recent release my app started crashing on launch. The crash is not related to changes that was made to app, because even reverting changes won't help.
here is the stacktrace:
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8004cd521 __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff8000837e8 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8004cd40f -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   Dreamhome                              0x104d048f4 -[RCTAppDelegate bundleURL] + 52
4   Dreamhome                              0x1043d7091 -[EXAppDelegateWrapper createRCTRootViewFactory] + 65
5   Dreamhome                              0x104d039af -[RCTAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 223
6   Dreamhome                              0x1043d6f20 -[EXAppDelegateWrapper application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 112
7   Dreamhome                              0x10423df9f -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 207
8   UIKitCore                           0x7ff805cbc5bb -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 297
9   UIKitCore                           0x7ff805cbe320 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 4253
10  UIKitCore                           0x7ff805cc3ea3 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1241
11  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804fe2661 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
12  UIKitCore                           0x7ff8056d7e45 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 87
13  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804fe31bf __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
14  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804fe2c20 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 249
15  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804fe3008 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 813
16  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804fe2834 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 341
17  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804fefe25 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 174
18  UIKitCore                           0x7ff805584484 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 865
19  UIKitCore                           0x7ff8056f64c3 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 261
20  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804fefab4 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 347
21  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804dc04db __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.613 + 877
22  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804dbee90 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 245
23  UIKitCore                           0x7ff804dc0043 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 252
24  UIKitCore                           0x7ff805cc26e3 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 672
25  UIKitCore                           0x7ff8055b9925 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 353
26  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a16db4 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 406
27  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a4aa0b __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.254 + 279
28  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a26a78 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 213
29  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a4a705 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 328
30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8001796d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80017d1e2 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 508
32  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a7635f __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
33  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a76239 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 188
34  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a76387 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 19
35  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800429fb3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
36  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800429ef5 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
37  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8004296f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215
38  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800423e27 __CFRunLoopRun + 919
39  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8004236ad CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
40  GraphicsServices                    0x7ff8103da08f GSEventRunModal + 137
41  UIKitCore                           0x7ff805cc0ad1 -[UIApplication _run] + 972
42  UIKitCore                           0x7ff805cc5551 UIApplicationMain + 123
43  Dreamhome                              0x10423e6d0 main + 96
44  dyld_sim                               0x1077023e0 start_sim + 10
45  dyld                                   0x10c4ac366 start + 1942

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x10779a14a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x108107ebd pthread_kill + 262
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff80016ddbc __abort + 145
3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff80016dd2b abort + 148
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff8002c6cf2 abort_message + 241
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff8002b94fa demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff800061fba _objc_terminate() + 96
7   Dreamhome                              0x104531055 FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 325
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff8002c614b std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 6
9   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff8002c6106 std::terminate() + 54
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8001796ec _dispatch_client_callout + 28
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80017d1e2 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 508
12  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a7635f __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
13  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a76239 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 188
14  FrontBoardServices                  0x7ff807a76387 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 19
15  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800429fb3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
16  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800429ef5 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
17  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8004296f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215
18  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800423e27 __CFRunLoopRun + 919
19  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8004236ad CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
20  GraphicsServices                    0x7ff8103da08f GSEventRunModal + 137
21  UIKitCore                           0x7ff805cc0ad1 -[UIApplication _run] + 972
22  UIKitCore                           0x7ff805cc5551 UIApplicationMain + 123
23  Dreamhome                              0x10423e6d0 main + 96
24  dyld_sim                               0x1077023e0 start_sim + 10
25  dyld                                   0x10c4ac366 start + 1942

Here are my dependencies:
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-config": "~0.18.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.1.2",
    "@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.28",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.79",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "expo": "^51.0.9",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.4.1",
    "expo-application": "~5.9.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "^4.0.15",
    "expo-dev-launcher": "^4.0.16",
    "expo-dev-menu": "^5.0.14",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.6",
    "expo-localization": "~15.0.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-store-review": "~7.0.2",
    "i18next": "^23.11.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "posthog-react-native": "^2.11.6",
    "qs": "^6.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^13.3.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-encrypted-storage": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "13.8.6",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },

